# Java ResultSet.getBigDecimal() scale issue with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Using `Oracle 11g`.

Reading a `number(18, 8)` column from it using JDBC `ResultSet.getBigDecimal(columnName)` - the value is `1`, and that is what is returned. However, I want it to return `1.00000000`.

Is there a way to get that? I tried `ResultSet.getBigDecimal(columnName, 8)` (I know it's deprecated, but wanted to try it anyway). Did not work.

Comment: There isn't much difference between 1 and 1.00000000. You may write some formatting code that prints the required number of decimal places.

Comment: @laune there're many such columns in my project with same requirement, so trying to find out if there's a better way than writing the formatting logic myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be the solution:

```
ResultSet.getBigDecimal(columnName).setScale(8);
```

Comment: Was the first thing I tried... did not work... now it does! Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( "1.0" );
System.out.println( bd );
bd = bd.setScale( 6 );
System.out.println( bd );
```

The scale property affects BigDecimal.toString()